# Tableview Cell Not Expanding When I tap On Section Button

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I Creating A Tableview With Expanding and Collapsing Feature. My issue is When I tap on section Button of any section only first section is Expand.If i click on any other section than again only first section will expand. I have A xib class for custom Section , I have added a button for expanding section.

Here's My Code

I'm returning 4 sections.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> 
    Int {
    
        return (sections[section].collapsed!) ? 0 : 4
}
```

@objc Class to handle functionality

```
 @objc func toggleCollapse(sender: UIButton) {
  let section = sender.tag
  let collapsed = sections[section].collapsed
  sections[section].collapsed = !collapsed!
self.wareHouseTable.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
}
```

My Model Class

```
struct Section {
var name: String!
var items: [String]!
var collapsed: Bool!

init(name: String, items: [String]) {
self.name = name
self.items = items
self.collapsed = true
  
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand and collapsed functionality in simple way.

1. First set button tag from cellfor row in tableview datasource method
2. Second get that tag in button action method and do your required code.

**Tableview DataSource & Delegate**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.buttonExpand.tag = indexPath.section
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (sections[section].collapsed!) ? 0 : 4
}
```

Button action

```
@IBAction func actionExpand(_ sender:UIButton) {
    let senderTag = IndexPath(item: sender.tag, section: 0) /// Return Indexpath
    sections[senderTag.section].collapsed = !sections[senderTag.section].collapsed
    self.wareHouseTable.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: senderTag.section) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
}
```